# checking for sting in pandas column and modifying another

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on cleaning a dataframe. The dataframe contains three columns `order_id` `'order_item'` and `'order_type`. The order type can be: breakfast, lunch, or dinner. I want to compare each item in the order to confirm it matches the order type. If not, I would like to drop the tuple that contains the wrong item.

The menus are as follow:

```
breakfastMenu=['Pancake', 'Coffee', 'Eggs', 'Cereal']
dinnerMenu=['Salmon', 'Fish&Chips', 'Pasta', 'Shrimp']
lunchMenu=['Steak', 'Fries', 'Burger', 'Chicken', 'Salad']
```

For example you can see in the first line, the **lunch** order contains **coffee** which is not correct. And **dinner** include **Egg**.

sample of the dataframe:

```
    order_id    order_type  order_items
0    ORDB10489  Lunch        [('Coffee', 4), ('Salad', 10), ('Chicken', 8)]
1    ORDZ00319  Dinner       [('Fish&Chips', 9), ('Pasta', 5), ('Eggs', 3)]
2   ORDB00980   Dinner       [('Pasta', 6), ('Fish&Chips', 10)]
3    ORDY10003  Breakfast    [('Coffee', 2), ('Cereal', 1)]
4   ORDK04121   Lunch        [('Steak', 9), ('Chicken', 5)]
```

I don't have enough experience with pandas data frames. But my idea is to create a `for loop` with `if conditions`. The loop will compare the first item in each `tuple` to the `order_type` and the corresponding **menu list**. If the item is not in the corresponding list the tuple will be dropped.

This draft code is just a beginning but it is similar to what I want to achieve:

```
if dirtyData['order_type'].str.contains('Breakfast').any()\
        and eval(dirtyData['order_items'][0])[0][0] not in breakfastMenu:
            print(dirtyData['order_id'])
```

*I add `eval` to convert the list of tuples from a string to a list.*

any input is appreciated 
Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `apply` with a custom function.

**Ex:**

```
import ast

breakfastMenu=['Pancake', 'Coffee', 'Eggs', 'Cereal']
dinnerMenu=['Salmon', 'Fish&Chips', 'Pasta', 'Shrimp']
lunchMenu=['Steak', 'Fries', 'Burger', 'Chicken', 'Salad']

check_val = {'Breakfast': breakfastMenu, 'Dinner': dinnerMenu, "Lunch": lunchMenu}

data = [['ORDB10489', 'Lunch', "[('Coffee', 4), ('Salad', 10), ('Chicken', 8)]"],
 ['ORDZ00319', 'Dinner', "[('Fish&Chips', 9), ('Pasta', 5), ('Egg', 3)]"],
 ['ORDB00980', 'Dinner', "[('Pasta', 6), ('Fish&Chips', 10)]"],
 ['ORDY10003', 'Breakfast', "[('Coffee', 2), ('Cereal', 1)]"],
 ['ORDK04121', 'Lunch', "[('Steak', 9), ('Chicken', 5)]"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['order_id', 'order_type', 'order_items'])
df["order_items"] = df["order_items"].apply(ast.literal_eval)
df["order_items"] = df.apply(lambda x: [i for i in x["order_items"] if i[0] in check_val.get(x["order_type"], [])], axis=1)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
    order_id order_type                     order_items
0  ORDB10489      Lunch     [(Salad, 10), (Chicken, 8)]
1  ORDZ00319     Dinner   [(Fish&Chips, 9), (Pasta, 5)]
2  ORDB00980     Dinner  [(Pasta, 6), (Fish&Chips, 10)]
3  ORDY10003  Breakfast      [(Coffee, 2), (Cereal, 1)]
4  ORDK04121      Lunch      [(Steak, 9), (Chicken, 5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I think there is a solution without any essential for loops. Just using some joins. But before we can achieve that, we have to bring the data to a more suitable shape.

```
flattened_items = df.order_items.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index().assign(
    **{"order_item": lambda x:x[0].str[0], "item_count": lambda x:x[0].str[1]})

print(flattened_items.head())
   level_0  level_1                0  order_item  item_count
0        0        0      (Coffee, 4)      Coffee           4
1        0        1      (Salad, 10)       Salad          10
2        0        2     (Chicken, 8)     Chicken           8
3        1        0  (Fish&Chips, 9)  Fish&Chips           9
4        1        1       (Pasta, 5)       Pasta           5
```

So essentially, I just flattened the list of tuple into two columns. Note, for your setup to work, you might need to run `reset_index` one on the original Dataframe df (otherwise it's like your sample from Dataframe)

Next we create a Dataframe that apps meals to items via

```
flattend_orders = pd.merge(df[["order_id", "order_type"]], 
         flattened_items[["level_0","order_item", "item_count"]],
left_index=True, right_on="level_0").drop("level_0", axis=1)

meal_dct = {"Breakfast": breakfastMenu, "Lunch": lunchMenu, "Dinner": dinnerMenu}

meal_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(meal_dct, orient="index").stack().reset_index(
).drop("level_1", axis=1).rename(columns={"level_0": "Meal", 0: "Item"})
```

which looks like

```
print(meal_df.head())
        Meal     Item
0  Breakfast  Pancake
1  Breakfast   Coffee
2  Breakfast     Eggs
3  Breakfast   Cereal
4      Lunch    Steak
```

Now, we can just do an inner join on the `order_type` and `order_item`

```
merged = pd.merge(flattend_orders, meal_df, left_on=["order_type", "order_item"],
right_on=["Meal", "Item"]).drop(["Meal", "Item"], axis=1)
```

and we obtain

```
    order_id order_type  order_item  item_count
0  ORDB10489      Lunch       Salad          10
1  ORDB10489      Lunch     Chicken           8
2  ORDK04121      Lunch     Chicken           5
3  ORDZ00319     Dinner  Fish&Chips           9
4  ORDB00980     Dinner  Fish&Chips          10
5  ORDZ00319     Dinner       Pasta           5
6  ORDB00980     Dinner       Pasta           6
7  ORDY10003  Breakfast      Coffee           2
8  ORDY10003  Breakfast      Cereal           1
9  ORDK04121      Lunch       Steak           9
```

Now, this is maybe already good enough, but you might prefer to have a list of tuples back. To this end:

```
merged.groupby(["order_id", "order_type"]).apply(lambda x: list(zip(x["order_item"], 
x["item_count"]))).reset_index().rename(columns={0:"order_items"})
```

gives

```
    order_id order_type                     order_items
0  ORDB00980     Dinner  [(Fish&Chips, 10), (Pasta, 6)]
1  ORDB10489      Lunch     [(Salad, 10), (Chicken, 8)]
2  ORDK04121      Lunch      [(Chicken, 5), (Steak, 9)]
3  ORDY10003  Breakfast      [(Coffee, 2), (Cereal, 1)]
4  ORDZ00319     Dinner   [(Fish&Chips, 9), (Pasta, 5)]
```

Note that the ugliness here is due to converting data from (maybe) insufficient formats. Also all for loops and apples just come from data transformation.

Essentially, my answer can be summarized as:

```
pd.merge(df, df_meal)
```

if we assume just the right data format.
Btw, I just chose `item_count` as a name as a best guess.

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful reply. I applied it on the sample and it works fine.

But when I tried to apply it to my entire dataframe, I get different results. For example: for the first code `flattened_orders`. My output for `0` column looks like this `[('Coffee', 4), ('Salad', 10), ('Chicken', 8)]` instead of tuples. Any idea why is this happening?


Thank again.

Comment: I updated my post to what my original dataframe looks like.

Comment: Is the only difference just the first column with the index? How do the `order_item` and `oder_count` column look like? Otherwise I don't see a difference. What you should try is: I'm using a lot of chained function calls (separated by the dot). Just explore them iteratively. Maybe this can help you understand what the functions are doing

Answer (score 0):

This is something you probably want to do in an Apply-function. Given that the `breakfastMenu`, `dinnerMenu` and `lunchMenu` are defined on the top of the script, the following function would work:

```py
def check_correct(x):
    if x['order_type'] == 'lunch':
        current_menu = lunchMenu
    elif x['order_type'] == 'dinner':
        current_menu = dinnerMenu
    else:
        current_menu= breakfastMenu

    current_menu = [x.lower() for x in current_menu]

    return_list = []

    for item, _ in x['order_items']:
        return_list.append(item.lower() in current_menu)

    return return_list
```

You can create a new column inside the DataFrame with:
`df.apply(check_correct, axis = 1)`. It will give you a list with the True and False mathes. The first line would result in the following output:

```py
[False, True, True]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    new = []
    if row["order_type"] == "Breakfast":
        order_type = breakfastMenu
    elif row["order_type"] == "Dinner":
        order_type = dinnerMenu
    elif row["order_type"] == "Lunch":
        order_type = lunchMenu
    else:
        continue

    a = row["order_items"][1:-1]
    b = a.split(",")
    for i in range(0,len(b),2):
        meal = b[i].strip()[2:-1]
        if meal in order_type:
            new.append([meal, b[i+1]])

    row["order_items_new"] = new

print(df["order_items_new"])

0     [[Salad,  10)], [Chicken,  8)]]  
1   [[Fish&Chips,  9)], [Pasta,  5)]]  
2  [[Pasta,  6)], [Fish&Chips,  10)]]  
3      [[Coffee,  2)], [Cereal,  1)]]  
4      [[Steak,  9)], [Chicken,  5)]]
```

Comment: This return an error in `b`. it says `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`